# tkinter polygons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm relatively new to tkinter, and I'm making a Game which uses only squares. the book I'm copying off only shows triangles. Here is the code:

```
# The tkinter launcher (Already complete)
from tkinter import *
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800
window = Tk()
window.title ('VOID')
c = Canvas (window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='black')
c.pack()
# Block maker (Issue)
ship_id = c.create_polygon (5, 5, 5, 25, 30, 15, fill='red')
```

I don't get any errors, it is just the string of numbers, `(5, 5, 5, 25, 30, 15)` which I don't get, as I'm trying to make a square.

Comment: if you want to make a rectangle you must give it four x/y coordinates rather than 3.

Comment: You can simply google how to do this. It will be listed on several sites and many answer here already on stack overflow. Take a look at the [tkinter docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) on the canvas widget.

Comment: OP, did any of the proposed answers answer your question?

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt Yes, but I'm experiencing other issues. I'm gonna post about it.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract of [`Canvas.create_polygon` definition](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_polygon.html):

> As displayed, a polygon has two parts: its outline and its interior. Its geometry is specified as a series of vertices [(x0, y0), (x1, y1), … (xn, yn)] (...)
>
> `id = C.create_polygon(x0, y0, x1, y1, ..., option, ...)`

So you need to pass the coordinates of the square in this specified order.
For example:

```
myCanvas.create_polygon(5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5)
```

can be read as

```
myCanvas.create_polygon(5,5, 5,10, 10,10, 10,5)
```

will create a square whose vertices are `(5, 5)`, `(5, 10)`, `(10, 10)` and `(10, 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_polygon.html) some info on the `create_polygon` function ([official docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)).

According to the nmt.edu page, the format of the function call is

```
id = C.create_polygon(x0, y0, x1, y1, ..., option, ...)
```

This means that the `ship_id = c.create_polygon (5, 5, 5,  25, 30, 15,  fill='red')` call creates a polygon with the following vertices: `(5,5), (5,25), (30, 15)` and fills the polygon with red.

If you want to create a square, you'd have to do the following:

```
ship_id = c.create_polygon (5, 5, 5,  25, 25, 25, 25, 5,  fill='red')
```

which creates a rectangle with vertices (5,5), (5,25), (25,25), (25,5).

If you wanted a more reproducible way to make ships, you could do something like

```
def ship (x,y): 
    return [x-5, y-5, x+5, y-5, x+5, y+5, x-5, y+5]
ship_id = c.create_polygon(*ship(100, 500),  fill='red')
```

The above would create sort of a factory for ships (the lambda function) in which you specify the x and y for the center of the ship and then it gives a list of the vertices that can be used for the `create_polygon` function.

You could even take this a step further to specify ship size with a tweaked lambda function

```
def ship (x,y,w,h): 
    return [x-w/2, y-h/2, x+w/2, y-h/2, x+w/2, y+h/2, x-w/2, y+h/2]
ship_id = c.create_polygon(*ship(100, 500, 8, 8),  fill='red')
```

Comment: Just as a remark: assigning a `lambda` expression is generally not recommended, using `def` is better. Reference: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), no anchor but ctrl+f -> lambda.

Comment: @Rightleg
Ah, hadn't realized that.  Makes sense wrt debugging, readability, and the sole advantage that lambda brings. Thanks for setting me straight.